# What is the definition of "with the sides still far apart"?

Tags: meaning

The headline is:

> "Players and owners could keep negotiating, but with the sides still far apart, baseball has its first work stoppage since the 1994-95 strike."

What is meant by "with the sides still far apart"? Does it refers to players and team owner diverging in opinion?

Comment: Yes, presumably that's what it means. The negotiations have not resolved the sides' differences.

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. In terms of contract negotiations, if two sides are "far apart", that means that their positions are very dissimilar, and that means there no agreement has been reached. Because this is about baseball player contracts, without an agreement, the players do not play any games.

Comment: [Apart adjective 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apart): "holding different opinions"

Answer (score -1):

Yes--they are not close to coming to agreement.  This is an adversarial situation, yet the two sides (the players' union and the owners) will both suffer consequences if there are games cancelled next April.  There is an understanding that they need to "come together" and agree on a new collective contract, but such an agreement would require the union and the owners to compromise a great deal on several matters.